# Move my-account to out of dropdown in top-link

Tags: magento2

[image]

I want to remove My Account out of dropdown in header, and remove this dropdown with customer name, how can i do this? i have this follow xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links"  >

         <referenceBlock name="my-account-link"/>               

            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           
            <!-- <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />   -->
            <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />  
</referenceBlock>
```

In short: i want to remove this dropdown in customer name, and add my account side by contact for example.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand **remove this dropdown in customer name**?

Comment: Where is "Vendedor maroto 1", is a dropdown, and inside that, have My Account, and logout, i want to remove the dropdown, and put My Account separately. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I just want that in header -> "welcome message, "My Account", "Contact", "Logout"